# How to understand what a loop does in this Python program?

Tags: python, logic

How can I understand the logic of the following function?

```
def spy_game(nums):

    code = [0,0,7,'x']
    
    for num in nums:
        if num == code[0]:
            code.pop(0)   # code.remove(num) also works
       
    return len(code) == 1
```

Comment: Which line are you having trouble understanding?

Answer (score 1):

The function compares the object elements from *nums* (it seems to be an array) with the values in *code*, all in sequence.

Let's say that nums is [2,0,1,0].

- The first iteration in the loop will find *num* to be 2, and that is compared with *code[0]* which is 0 so the comparison is false and continues with the following number.
- The second iteration *num* will be 0, and that is compared with *code[0]* which is 0, so the comparison is true and pops the first element in *code*, the one we used to compare. Now *code* is [0,7,'x'] because the first element was removed.
- Third iteration has *num* as 1 and the comparison with *code[0]* that again is 0 is false and continues with the next number.
- Fourth iteration has *num* as 0 and it is compared with 0, so the comparison is true and again that first element of code is removed. Now code will be [7,'x'].

The result in this case is false because code ends with 2 elements instead of 1. The result will be true if the parameter *nums* includes in sequence the digits [0,0,7], no matter if they are mixed with other values. For example, this function will return true as well if you *nums* is [0,5,4,0,1,2,7] because the digits from code appears in the list.

The last 'x' is used in the function just to have some value in code to compare some element in *nums* after the last 7. For example, if there were no 'x' and *nums* is [0,0,7,1] the function will fail because once you try to compare the last element in *nums* you will have no more elements in *code* and *code[0]* will fail.

Answer (score 0):

This code compare two lists "nums" and "code". if elements from both lists equal then it remove this element from list "code". and finally if length of list "code" equal 1 it should return True

Method "pop" remove the item at the given position in the list, and return it
Method "remove" remove the first item from the list whose value is equal to x

Answer (score 0):

The method iterates over a input list `nums` and checks if the current `num` is equal to the first element in the `code` array. If the elements are equal, the first element of `code` is removed.

At the end of the code the program checks if the `code` array is containing exactly one element and if thats the case `true` is returned